# Lattice without 0 , 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

I am looking for an example of  **Lattice** that has no **$0$ , $1$** elements.

Comment: According to wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order) ) the positive integers form a lattice under the min and max operators, with no top element, but a bottom element. Then perhaps the set of all integers is a lattice with neither top nor bottom? (Here "top element" means 1 in the lattice framework, and "bottom element" 0, I just didn't want to invoke confusion)

Answer (score 5):

Take any totally ordered set with no minimum and no maximum. $\mathbb{Z}$ will do for instance.